# Prop keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently trying to create a table where each row has a checkbox that can be enabled or disabled. 
I have created 3 files:

- ChangeUserGroup.jsx - This is where the data is read from a json file
- UserGroupForm.jsx - Starts the form and passes the *this.prop.permissions* on to the next file, which contains the table and the checkboxes.
- TableShowPermissions.jsx - Contains the table and the problematic function + checkbox

I would like for the data in the ChangeUserGroup.jsx state(called **groupDetails.permissions**) to control if the checkbox for the given permission is initialized with "defaultChecked". But i am getting the following error:

[image: The error given]

The files contain the following:

**ChangeUserGroup.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

import { Container, Row, Col, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, Table, Button } from 'reactstrap';

import jsonData from '_testdata/userGroups';
import LoadingIcon from '_components/LoadingIcon';
import UserGroupForm from '_components/UserGroupForm';

class ChangeUserGroup extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            userGroupId: 0,
            groupDetails: []
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        const { userGroupId } = this.props.match.params

        this.setState({
            userGroupId: userGroupId
        });

        jsonData.userGroups.filter((a) => a.id.toString() === userGroupId).map((b) => this.setState({
            groupDetails: b,
            isLoading: false
        }));
    }

    render() {

        const { groupDetails, isLoading } = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return <LoadingIcon />;
        }

        return (
            <>
                <Helmet>
                    <title>{global.siteName + " - Brugergrupper"}</title>
                </Helmet>

                <main>
                    <section className="section section-shaped section-lg">

                        <Container>
                            <Row className="justify-content-center">
                                <Col lg="12">
                                    <Card className="bg-secondary shadow border-0">
                                        <CardHeader className="bg-white">
                                            <h1 className="text-center">{groupDetails.name}</h1>

                                        </CardHeader>
                                        <CardBody className="px-lg-5 py-lg-5">

                                            <UserGroupForm 
                                                id={groupDetails.id} 
                                                groupName={groupDetails.name} 
                                                position={groupDetails.position}
                                                permissions={groupDetails.permissions} />

                                        </CardBody>

                                    </Card>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Container>
                    </section>
                </main>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export { ChangeUserGroup };
```

**UserGroupForm.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Form } from "reactstrap";

import CustomFormInput from '_components/FormStuff/CustomFormInput';
import TableShowPermissions from '_components/UserGroups/TableShowPermissions';

class UserGroupForm extends Component {

    render() {

        const { id, groupName, position, permissions } = this.props;


        return (
            <Form>
                <CustomFormInput pLabel="Gruppe navn" pIcon="fa-user" pType="text" pShowLabel="on" pValue={groupName} />
                <CustomFormInput pLabel="Gruppe position" pIcon="fa-user" pType="text" pShowLabel="on" pValue={position} />
                <hr />
                <TableShowPermissions 
                    thePermissions={permissions} />
            </Form>

        );
    }
}

export default UserGroupForm;
```

**TableShowPermissions.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import jsonData from 'UserPermissions';

import { Table, Button } from "reactstrap";

class TableShowPermissions extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.checkIfPermissionAdded = this.checkIfPermissionAdded.bind(this);
    }

    checkIfPermissionAdded(checkPerm) {
        const { thePermissions } = this.props;

        thePermissions.split('|').map(permC => {
            //console.log(checkPerm + " -- " + permC)
            if (checkPerm === permC) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <Table className="align-items-center table-bordered" responsive>
                <thead className="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Permission navn</th>
                        <th scope="col">Beskrivelse</th>
                        <th scope="col" />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    {jsonData.permissions.map(perm => (
                        <tr key={perm.id}>
                            <th scope="row">
                                {perm.permission}
                            </th>

                            <td>
                                {perm.description}
                            </td>

                            <td className="text-right">
                                <label className="custom-toggle">
                                    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.checkIfPermissionAdded(perm.permission)} />
                                    <span className="custom-toggle-slider rounded-circle" />
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}

                </tbody>
            </Table>

        );
    }
}

export default TableShowPermissions;
```

JSON DATA

```
{
    "userGroups": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Administrator",
            "position": "Admin",
            "permissions": "ADMIN_ROOT|"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Moderator",
            "position": "Mod",
            "permissions": "ADMIN_SETTINGS_GENERAL|ADMIN_CASES_SEEALL|ADMIN_SETTINGS_CATEGORIES"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Supporters",
            "position": "Supporter",
            "permissions": "ADMIN_CASES_SEEALL|"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: And new to React so be overbearing ;)

Comment: I'm not pro at react, but maybe I can help, try to console.log on UserGroupForm to see if the value of permissions getting there correctly `const { id, groupName, position, permissions } = this.props; console.log(permissions);`

Comment: Hey Spacedog :) I tried that, and it says "undefined"... The weird thing is, when i remove the TableShowPermissions component from UserGroupForm it gives the correct value in console :) But it renders the console log 4 times and only the last 2 is with the correct value

Comment: So at the end of componentDidMount on ChangeUserGroup, console.log what do you have in `groupDetails`

Comment: If i remove the call on the function (checkIfPermissionAdded) and console.log(this.props) there is also no issue seeing the correct values... It seems like it renders before this.props value is recieved?

Comment: If i add console.log(groupDetails) to the end of componentDidMount i get an empty array... But if i put the console.log in the start of the render i get the correct values @SpaceDogCS

Comment: `jsonData.userGroups.filter(a => a.id.toString() === userGroupId).map(b => this.setState({ groupDetails: b, isLoading: false, }) )`. You don't need to use `map` for looping, instead use `forEach`. You are calling `this.setState` inside a loop : This is problematic.

Comment: How does the data in `jsonData.userGroups` look like? Can you add that data in your question? I can suggest better way to what you tried to do with `map` and `setState` inside `map`.

Comment: I've added it to the question @AjeetShah :D See "JSON DATA"

Comment: `const filtered = jsonData.userGroups.filter(item => String(item.id) === String(userGroupId));
this.setState({ isLoading: false, groupDetails: filtered })` I hope this is what you tried to do there with `map`. This might not solve your problem but might make your code better. try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Weird, what is the value of `userGroupId`? is it a string or an integer? I see you're using `===` it can return false if one is an integer and the other an string

Comment: @SpaceDogCS It should be string as it is coming from `this.props.match.params`. But @AndersG can do `String(userGroupId)`.

Comment: `filtered` is an array. If you think that there can be only one matching item with this `String(item.id) === String(userGroupId)` condition. You need to do: `this.setState({ isLoading: false, groupDetails: filtered[0] || {} })` Or use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter`.

Comment: You should have created a minimal example of your problem. Try this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-grass-gtqel?file=/src/App.js), it is working fine after I fixed some bits, but I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13477#issuecomment-415982277) about "checked" and "defaultChecked". Also, check [this in doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).

Answer (score 1):

If after a few react renders you do have the value, it most likely means it just isn't there yet in the first renders *(this can happen if you are getting the data from a request)*.

You can either add an `if` condition to only run the split when `thePermissions` exist or add a default value to it.

```js
    checkIfPermissionAdded(checkPerm) {
        const { thePermissions } = this.props;

        if (thePermissions) {
          thePermissions.split('|').map(permC => {
              //console.log(checkPerm + " -- " + permC)
              if (checkPerm === permC) {
                return true;
              }
          });
        }

        return false;
    }
```

or

```js
    checkIfPermissionAdded(checkPerm) {
        const { thePermissions = '' } = this.props;

        thePermissions.split('|').map(permC => {
            //console.log(checkPerm + " -- " + permC)
            if (checkPerm === permC) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

It is possible that none is what you desire in your code but it might help you out knowing why it is happening.

Comment: I think it is it, I get my self in this mistake everytime

Comment: I've tried adding a if-statement but all it does, is not to render the function at all.. (As if it is never anything else than "undefined".. I think the problem lies in how i get the data from 1 component to another :)

Comment: Also I forgot to note but the `return true` is inside the map, and will not return true for the actual function as far as I know but to that map iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your Loading initial state as true. Set your state in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        userGroupId: props.match.params,
        groupDetails: []
    }
}
```

Remove the first two setState from your componentDidMount. Each time a setState is called the render fucntion is called.